# Serving pytorch model with django and uwsgi, how can the system support multi requests concurrency?

Tags: django, pytorch, uwsgi

If I street-test the API with 10 concurrency requests:

- using django built-in server, `python3 manage.py runserver`, the average response time is about 10 times longer than 1 concurrency request
- using uwsgi to start 10 progress, the average response time is about 5 times longer than 1 concurrency request

How can I handle multi requests in instant response time?